# Does ubuntu software center download 64bit apps?

Tags: software-center

Noob question: when using the 64bit version of ubuntu (xubuntu in this case) and I install something through the software center, will it get the 64bit app for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Software Center, as well as Synaptic, poke around in your system and determine what you need, and get it for you, 64-bit or 32-bit.

Comment: Speaking about synaptic, when I download a .deb file off the internet (for example, I download google chrome off google's webpage) can I install that .deb file with synaptic? (just like it would install with the software center when i double click it)

Comment: Would you mind, please, making that a separate question? The Stack Exchange system is intended to provide a compendium of good questions for others to search through when they need answers, to build a Knowledge Base as we answer questions which come up. Therefore, this and all other SE sites want one-issue-per-post queries, and splitting that question off into its own post is preferred.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: And, although you did not ask, http://askubuntu.com/questions/99055/installing-software-from-package-sources-vs-downloadable-deb-files explains why it's better to get an app from Software Center or Synaptic. Since Chrome has Google's 'phone-home so we can see where you're browsing' proprietary code, you may instead wish to get Chromium from Synaptic which is the foundation of the Chrome browser without the "phone-home" stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It will get the 64 bit app(if its available) if you are using the 64 bit version of ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

The software center is just a frontend for aptdaemon, which is a transaction based package management service. It behaves the same way as `apt-get`, which reads the current architecture. If you select a package to install it will check the current architecture and install it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, yes. But most apps is in 32-bit. The only 64-bit apps is drivers, kernels, and maybe some utilities software.

32-bit apps usually include a code to check for 64-bit OS, if detected, it'll automatically enable all 64-bit features, otherwise it'll stay as 32-bit (x86). This is because there are some computers which couldn't run (or don't have) 64-bit OS. As a software developer, it will be too cumbersome to provide 32-bit and 64-bit software separately, and 32-bit is universal, can be run on both 32-bit and 64-bit OS. So, for the moment, most software still use 32-bit, until 32-bit becomes obsolete.