# Can I use Launchpad to replace the ubuntu software centre?

Tags: software-center, synaptic, launchpad

I found https://launchpad.net/ there's loads of applications to choose from there it seems like all of them. You've got to add the ppa, update then install the applications. This can be pretty cumbersome if you plan on installing a few with the terminal.

Is there a launchpad application that replaces the ubuntu software centre? Does the synaptic package manager index everything in launchpad? maybe that's what I'm looking for let me know cheers :)

After asking https://askubuntu.com/questions/532226/why-dont-developers-upload-to-the-ubuntu-software-centre

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/99055/installing-software-from-package-sources-vs-downloadable-deb-files

Comment: http://blog.launchpad.net/ppa/adding-a-ppas-key-to-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Launchpad isn't a software repository. It's a developer platform around software for Ubuntu and other Debian-based distributions. As such it includes many software repositories, that are searchable with software center once they're configured locally.

There's a good reason to not include repositories where anybody can publish software to by default, because then anybody could trick people into installing their unsafe or malicious software packages instead of the official ones (see also “[Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/175814)”). Canonical decides for themselves which packages go into their “official” repositories to mitigate the risk of harmful or malicious code. Other developers cannot insert software into those repositories without Canonical's consent.

Comment: So launchpad is like github, Definitely worth having a protocol where ppa's are marked as safe or red flagged. piratebay.se uses different coloured skulls to mark whether a users upload quality is good. Do you think there's room for another third party software centre?

Comment: Why don't developers upload to the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Not all software is indexed in the Ubuntu Software Centre. There are tons of reviews and online content about great applications that's don't feature in the Ubuntu software centre. Hardly any of the search queries work, Why is that?

Comment: Please see the update on my answer. Money quote: “Other developers cannot insert software into those repositories without Canonical's consent.”

Comment: Addendum: “software center” is a locally running application that manages software packages from the locally configured software repositories. I would be very concerned if random people could “upload” their software to my computer.

Comment: @IsaacTanner-Dempsey: To conclude, it seems like you need to do more research on the things you're asking questions about. Your ideas about the nature of Launchpad and the Ubuntu Software Center were quite a bit off and that has nothing to do with understanding simple technological ignorance (which would be fine by me). If you had done your reading, you could have seen, that you questions don't make sense and will result in answers that clarify the meaning of the words instead of answering your question.